# Compiling C++11 code with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2013, Version 12.0 Update 4, bails out on a C++11 include

```
#include <initializer_list>
```

with the error

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'initializer_list': No such file or directory
```

Yet the [features table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#featurelist) has this one as one of the features already in VS 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have multiple versions of Visual Studio, or if you are opening project created in older version, check that under "Project properties -> General -> Platform toolset" "Visual studio 2013 (v120)" is specified.

That would ensure that appropriate version of a compiler and Standard library will be picked up.

Answer (score 0):

The code should compile and does for me. Something about your project configuration or VS setup is broken.